# SQL Compact 4.0 Tools

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

Just want to find out if anyone has used or is currently using Sql Compact 4.0 for development. Basically we are looking for tools that can support the creation of change script similar to the one we have in Sql Server 2008 Management Studio.

If you are not sure what that feature is, basically whenever you make schema changes, you can simply generate the change script to be run elsewhere. I haven't come across any tools that can provide that kind of feature for Sql Compact 4.0.

Has anyone come across that kind of tool? If so, can you please let me know?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use my SQL Server Compact Toolbox (VS add-in or standalone) http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com to do schema diff scripting